# Excel autofill and adjust formulas

Tags: excel, vba

I made a code that adds columns to the end of a range with the function autofill in VBA. So when a column at the beginning of the range is deleted, the code will add a column at the end of the range.
So the range is always the same size. The range I mean is for example column N until the column DA.

This all works perfectly except for one thing. In column E (in front of the range N - DA) I have a formula that sums a certain range in the range N - DA. To determine which range must be summed I check a value (a week number) in the range N - DA. But when a column is added at the end, the formula in column E is not adjusted to extend again until column DA.

So how can I make it so that the formula in column E is adjusted until column DA when I use autofill in VBA? When I do it manually with selecting and dragging to the right in the worksheet it also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your VBA, after you add in the column at the end, add code that will adjust the formula. For example, let's say your sum formula is this:

```
=SUM(N1:DA5)
```

You already have the new last column in a variable (I'm assuming) so use it to adjust the formula. You can insert a formula programmatically something like this:

```
newLastColumn = "DB"
Range("E1").Formula = "=SUM(N1:" & newLastColumn & "5)"
```